# Register node as default executable for js files

Tags: node.js, platform

How can I register NodeJS as a default executable program for .js files on Windows and Linux

For example

```
//script01.js
console.log("I'm executable")
```

Then in cmd bash:

```
$: script.js 
I'm executable

$: |
```

On Windows I'm aware to the `ControlPanel/Programs/Make a file type always open in specific program` it work fine until I need to pass arguments to the script.

so let say I have :

```
 //script2.js
 console.log('argument 3 is :',process.argv[2])
```

then :

```
$: script2.js myArg
argument 3 is : undefind

$: |
```

instead of

```
$: script2.js myArg
argument 3 is : myArg

$: |
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `script.js` file, add a shebang to the top of the file to indicate the script should be run by the node interpreter:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

In your `package.json`, add `"bin": "path/to/script.js"` and when you `npm install` (or `npm link`), npm will create an executable `script.js` as well as `script.js.cmd` that will run on windows.

Alternatively, you can just use `node script.js` each time to run the script.

Comment: there can be a way to add more the one executable scripts to package.json ?

Comment: @perymimon Yes, and you can give them different names as well https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin

Comment: cool it work fine even for `.cmd` files . but now i'm curious how make `.js` files work on windows but not in `npm` project